# fftw: Why is my 2D DFT output not the same as the output from taking 1D DFT of each row?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fft, fftw

For my project, I have to take the DFT of a large 2D input matrix, process it, then convert it back with an IDFT and compare the results to the input matrix. My problem is in the 2D DFT step. I wrote a test with a small simple data set, which I execute in `main()`. I use the [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html) library for matrices and vectors. The output is this:

```
Using testM in a myTransform object:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
calculateDFT took 33 Microseconds
DFT
          (6,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)
(-1.5,0.866025)
         (15,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)
(-1.5,0.866025)
         (24,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)
(-1.5,0.866025)
IDFT
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Using testM in a myTransform2D object:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Default myTransform object created
DFT2D
          (45,0)  (-4.5,-2.59808)          (45,-0)
          (45,0) (-13.5,-7.79423)          (45,-0)
          (45,0)           (0,-0)          (45,-0)
IDFT
27.5 -0.5 -1.5 -8.5  8.5  7.5   -7   10    9
```

In the snippets below, `this->N = this->nRows * this->nCols`. The results of Test 1 and Test 2 should be the same, but they are obvisouly different. I have read the documentation over and over and still can't find why it's going wrong. fftw does row-major multi-dimensional transforms, `in` is filled per row of the matrix. The `transfer_output` function does not do anything with the values themselves, only converts the standard array to an `Eigen::Matrix`. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated. I have also tried to find similar posts here but none had my problem as far as I could find.

```
void test()
{
    RowVectorXf test(9);
    test << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
    // Prep matrix 
    Map<Matrix<float, 3, 3, RowMajor>> testM(test.data()); // convert test to rowmajor matrix

    // Test 1: feed the matrix to a myTransform object and take 1D DFTs and 1D IDFTs 
    std::cout << "Using testM in a myTransform object:\n" << testM << std::endl;
    myTransform testX1D(testM, 0);
    testX1D.vectorise();
    testX1D.calculateDFT();
    testX1D.calculateIDFT();
    std::cout << "DFT" << std::endl << testX1D.dft << std::endl;
    std::cout << "IDFT" << std::endl << testX1D.idft << std::endl; // works, too.

    .. Test 2: Feed the matrix to a myTransform2D object and take the 2D DFT and IDFT.
    std::cout << "Using testM in a myTransform2D object:\n" << testM << std::endl;
    myTransform2D testX(testM, 0); // 2D version 
    testX.vectorise(); // stored in testX.m which will hold the same as test but in a colmajor vector.
    testX.calculateDFT(); // where it goes wrong?
    std::cout << "DFT2D" << std::endl << testX.dft2D << std::endl;
    testX.calculateIDFT();
    std::cout << "IDFT" << std::endl << testX.idft << std::endl;
}
```

This is how I calculate the DFTs in each case, using the fftw library (fftwf because I use single precision to save memory and the values of the non-test data are on the order of -10000 to 10000, so I think that is not an issue).

```
void myTransform::calculateDFT()
/// Calculates discrete fourier transform of vectorised data `m`.
/** uses the FFTW library (https://fftw.org). The dft is stored in myTransform::dft*/
{
    //std::cout << m << std::endl;
    fftwf_complex* out;
    fftwf_plan p;
    out = (fftwf_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * this->nCols);
    float* in = new float[static_cast<const float&>(this->nCols)];
    p = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(this->nCols, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    // calculate DFT for each trace and assign it to a segment of this->dft
    unsigned int factor = 0;
    auto check = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int k = 0; k < this->nRows; k++)
    {
        factor = k * this->nCols;
        //TODO: if possible, fix this slow in[i] = ... part. 
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nCols; i++)
        {
            in[i] = this->m[factor + i];
        }
        p = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(this->nCols, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftwf_execute(p);
        this->transfer_output(out, k); // does nothing but add the output to a vector dft. 
    }
    delete [] in;
    fftwf_free(out);
    fftwf_destroy_plan(p);
}
```

And for the 2D DFT case: Here I use std::complex as specified on [fftw.org](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html#Complex-numbers). I allocate `nRows * (nCols/2 + 1)` single-precision floats as instructed [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data). For the 1D case, this is done in the 1D `transfer_output` function where `dft` is filled with `out[this->nCols - i]` for `i > this->nCols/2`

```
void myTransform2D::calculateDFT()
/// Should calculate the DFT in 2D with fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(n0, n1, *in, *out, flags).
{
    std::complex<float>* out;
    fftwf_plan p;
    out = (std::complex<float>*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(std::complex<float>) * this->nRows * (this->nCols/2+1)); // Hermitian symmetry for r2c transforms
    float* in = new float[this->N];
    in = (float*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(float) * this->N);
    p = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(this->nRows, this->nCols, in, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(out), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    // Fill input array
    for (int i = 0; i < this->nRows; i++)
    {
        int factor = i * this->nCols;
        for (int j = 0; j < this->nCols; j++)
        {
            in[factor + j] = this->m[factor + j];
        }
    }
    fftwf_execute(p);
    transfer_output(out);
    fftwf_free(in);
    fftwf_free(out);
    fftwf_destroy_plan(p);
}
```

I convert back to the time domain using the IDFT, again in both 1D and 2D. I don't know for sure if the 2D version works, as the DFT goes wrong. The 1D case works, so I show the 2D case only.

```
void myTransform2D::calculateIDFT()
/// Calculates inverse fourier transform of `this->dft2D`.
/** Also uses the FFTW library. Results might not be perfect as we use floats
    instead of doubles because of large data sizes. */
{
    float* out = new float[this->N];
    std::complex<float>* in; 
    fftwf_plan pr;
    in = (std::complex<float>*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(std::complex<float>) * this->N);
    out = (float*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(float) * this->N);
    pr = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_2d(this->nRows, this->nCols, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(in), out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    for (int i = 0; i < this->nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->nCols; j++)
        {
            in[i * this->nCols + j] = this->dft2D(i, j);
        }
    }

    fftwf_execute(pr);

    for (int i = 0; i < this->N; i++)
    {
        this->idft[i] = out[i] / this->N; // fftw does unnormalized inverse transforms.
    }

    fftwf_free(out);
    fftwf_free(in);
    fftwf_destroy_plan(pr);
}
```

EDIT: removed some code as suggested
EDIT2: removed image, added contents as text.

Comment: @Evg I removed some of the code and updated the output image. I hope you can make something of it now :)

Comment: @L.vanAgtmaal there are no images left in the question

Comment: I will edit the question, sorry.

Comment: A 2D FFT is equivalent to an FFT of all the rows, followed by an FFT of all the resulting columns. It looks like you're only doing the first part?

Comment: The rows are independent of each other. I see what you mean though... then why does the 1D version work?

Comment: You need to decide what is is you want to achieve, do you want M x N-point 1D FFTs, or do you want a single 2D MxN FFT ?

Comment: I need to process the result row-wise, so I guess I can use the quickest option. Since fftw is very efficient, I think their 2D version is better than my series of 1D FFTs. I will stick to the 2D version then.

Comment: 2D transform is not equivalent to `M` 1D ones.

Comment: I know that. Still, I can retrieve the original data with both. the 1D DFTs are
 `(6,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)
         (15,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)
         (24,0)
(-1.5,0.866025)` so very different indeed. But when I inverse transform those per 2, I get the original data.

Comment: @PaulR I checked what I need to achieve, it's a single 2D MxN FFT. Thanks for making me think about this, I had not realized it before.

Comment: @L.vanAgtmaal: no problem - it's all part of the learning experience. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer this question without full reproducible example that anyone can compile and test. So I will give the code that performs 2D forward and backward transforms and reference results.

**Forward.**

```
const auto fft_size = n * (n / 2 + 1);
auto out = (std::complex<float>*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(std::complex<float>) * fft_size);
auto p = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(n, n, in, (fftwf_complex*)(out), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(p);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < fft_size; ++i)
    std::cout << *(out + i) << ' ';
```

For the matrix in the row-major order

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the correct output is:

```
(45,0) (-4.5,2.59808) (-13.5,7.79423) (0,0) (-13.5,-7.79423) (0,0)
```

**Backward.**

```
auto in2 = (float*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(float) * n * n);
auto p2 = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_2d(n, n, (fftwf_complex*)(out), in2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(p2);

for (std::size_t row = 0; row < n; ++row) {
    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < n; ++col)
        std::cout << *(in2 + col + row * n) / (n * n) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs the original matrix.

---

Note that the output size of the forward transform (`fft_size`) is `n * (n / 2 + 1)` and not `n * n`. In your output I see 9 complex entries instead of 6. The size of `in` in the function `calculateIDFT()` is also wrong, and the way you copy values into it is probably wrong, too.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I think I know what I did wrong now. The `transfer_output()` functions use the symmetry to make an `nRows` x `nCols` dft2D matrix which is fed into the IDFT function. But the output is actually only `nRows`x `(nCols/2+1)` as you pointed out. I will try to put your suggestions to use now.